# UnicodeDecodeError when parsing XML on mac but works on PC

Tags: python, xml, ascii, lxml, parsexml

When parsing a `XML` file with:

```
from lxml import etree

with open('cortex_full.xml', 'r') as infile:
    root = etree.parse(infile)
```

I am getting the `UnicodeDecodeError` below.  This only happens on my Mac though - if I parse the same file with the same script on my work PC, everything works fine.

```
File "/Users/Desktop/CPET/xml_test2.py", line 5, in <module>
    root = etree.parse(infile)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3442, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:81701)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1832, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:118888)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1852, in lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:119171)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1747, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:117959)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1162, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:112686)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 595, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105881)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 702, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:107548)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 324, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:12152)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 373, in lxml.etree._FileReaderContext.copyToBuffer (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:103210)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 783: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This seems to be quite a common occurrence given the number of threads on here, however none of the suggested fixes seem to be working for this instance. Any ideas for getting it to work? Full `XML` file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dx0zfy9s5sd96uw/cortex_full.xml?dl=0)

Comment: are you using the same version of Python on both systems?

Comment: Yes, most up-to-date version of Python3 and lxml on both.

Comment: `with open('cortex_full.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:`

Comment: Interestingly, I tried that yesterday and it didn't work but when I tried it just now it works. I must have typed something different the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting an answer that worked for me for future reference.
Credit goes to @Burhan Khalid for the answer.

Need to set encoding to `utf-8` when opening the `xml` file.

```
with open('cortex_full.xml', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
```